# How do I enable a user to sudo without password?

Tags: bash, php, sudo

I have a php script with this:

```
<?php
#echo exec('whoami');

$output = shell_exec('bash /usr/local/svn/bash_repo/make-live');
echo "$output";
?>
```

The make-live script contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www-cake

sudo svn checkout file:///usr/local/svn/bash_repo/repo/

echo "Head revision has been pushed to live server"
```

So the PHP user who is `www-data` needs to have nopasswd for that script. I am told I need to add:

> www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:
>   /usr/local/svn/bash_repo/make-live

To sudoers to allow this. First I run `sudo visudo` but I have no experience with vi so I try to open it in gedit with `export EDITOR=gedit && sudo -E visudo` which then just opens a sudoers.tmp file which is empty. I add the line and save it. But it doesn't do save.

So I just try `sudo visudo` and I add the line right beneath this part:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/svn/bash_repo/make-live
```

I closed out sudoers and reopened to verify that it has saved. I even restart apache.

I run the php file and it still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes, how? May you please post the answer. I seem to be facing the a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding your apache user `www-data` to sudoers and then worse adding a no-password option is a REALLY BAD IDEA. It's a security issue to have the apache user being able to do anything as root and you should avoid it.

What you need to do is change the permissions of /var/www-cake so that www-data can write to it when you run `svn checkout` without the sudo.

Try this: `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www-cake`

Remove the sudo and try again.

Comment: I ran the command, I checked the permissions of the www-cake directory to verify that www-data is the owner. I removed "sudo" from the command in the make-live script. I then executing the php script by loading it in my browser. It did not work.

Comment: The fact that it didn't work is related to your PHP code/configuration, it is expected to work, sudo is not a solution.